# sql join of function

Tags: sql

I have a function that takes 2 parameters and return a table.
Is it possible to use this function in a select and show the 3 columns that it returns?
This is my query:

```
select a.PersonId, b.Passportnumber, dbo.fn_Passport(a.PersonId)
from Person a
```

thanks

Comment: I take it this is sql-server from your past questions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can use the APPLY operator

```
select a.PersonId, b.Passportnumber, p.col1, p.col2, p.col3
from Person a
OUTER APPLY dbo.fn_Passport(a.PersonId) p
```

I have assumed the column names are col1, col2, col3 for illustration.

You use **CROSS** APPLY when the function must return 1 or more rows to retain the Person record.  Use **OUTER** APPLY to keep the Person record even if the function results in no rows.  Basically

```
CROSS APPLY similar to INNER JOIN
OUTER APPLY similar to OUTER JOIN
```

[How to use APPLY](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

if your talking about fn_Passport-  it doesn't seem, that it is returning a table.

If it does - you can select only needed columns, or join via CROSS APPLY